# non-void function does not return a value in all control paths in C

Tags: c

I know that there are similar questions but I think I have not found an answer to my question. I am getting the error from the topic. I am not sure why this is as all controlled paths IMO return a value. I believe that the problem lies in a first for loop - when I commented it out code complied. But I do not know why a value should be returned after the loop, the function should proceed further. Am I wrong?

```
bool is_cycle (int winner, int loser)
{
        bool loser_is_winner = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++)
            {
              if (locked[loser][i] == true)
              {
                  loser_is_winner = true;
              }
            }

        if (loser_is_winner == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (loser == winner_fixed)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (loser_is_winner == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++)
            {
                if (locked[loser][i] == true)
                {
                    is_cycle(loser,i);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: The `else if (loser_is_winner == true)` branch doesn't return anything.

Comment: but that path leads to a recursion. Should it still return a value?

Comment: It should be `return is_cycle(loser,i);` for returning something, on the way back from recursion.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you don't need to compare with boolean values. Just do, e.g., `if (locked[loser][i])` or `if (!loser_is_winner)`.

Comment: @adabsurdum: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/what_is_truth_0x3f_ I wasn't ready to assume that. This isn't the only case I've seen where true and false had unexpected integer values either.

Comment: @Joshua -- `loser_is_winner` is declared as a `bool`. Since `locked` is defined elsewhere I suppose that it _could_ contain values other than `bool`....

Comment: @adabsurdum: It's C. If he doesn't include `stdbool.h` (and even today most C code doesn't) he can up and declare `bool` to do something else.

Comment: @Joshua -- yes, it is C. `bool` is standard C, and under the C tag it is assumed that questions are about C as defined in the current standard.

Answer (score 1):

This case doesn't have a return statement:

```
        else if (loser_is_winner == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++)
            {
                if (locked[loser][i] == true)
                {
                    is_cycle(loser,i);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you're going to return a value, you need to return a value on all paths, otherwise the return value is garbage.

Do you mean:

```
        else if (loser_is_winner == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i ++)
            {
                if (locked[loser][i] == true)
                {
                    return is_cycle(loser,i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Incidentally, this block is unreachable:

```
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Fun fact: if you access the non-returned return value on Itanium, your code might crash.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I thought there is no need to return a value where there is recursion and this return path will never be reached. In my example locked[loser][i] == true in at least 1 of cases (look at first for loop), thus I think "return false" will never be reached (like the block you mentioned)

Comment: @Bench Even though *you* know that particular `return false;` statement will never be reached, the compiler doesn't know that it will never be reached, so you need to return *something*.

Answer (score 1):

Every function that you expect that returns a value, you must sure that always reach the code(return). You have something like the next:

```c
bool myFunction(someParam) {
  //some code
  if(condition1){
    // do something
    return value1;
  } else if(condition2) {
    //do something
    return value2;
  } else if(condition3) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something
    return value4;
  }
}
```

You can notice that in *if* with the *condition3* not has a return, if you enter in this condition never reach any return. Check part of your code to try avoid this case.